# how do i check if an object exist in an array, if it is not in the array to push it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here I have a quiz (a Likert type quiz). Inside it, I want to collect the question number and the question-answer which I can add as a single object into the array. that much I have working.

I need to determine if the person were to change their answer on the quiz, and if they do I need to replace their old answer (which was saved in the array) to that index location. If they haven't answered a certain question yet, just push it at the index location of the question number.

```
let questions = [];


function get_id(xd,jf){

    let question = (xd.parentNode.id);
    let question_num = document.getElementById(question).getAttribute("value");
    let number = document.getElementById(jf).getAttribute("value");
    let new_answer = {Question:question_num, Answer:number};

    questions.push(new_answer);

    let found = questions.includes(new_answer);

    console.log(found);

    if (found == false) {
        questions.push(new_answer);

    };

    // if (questions.some... " i couldn't understand how to use the some method"

    //for (i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) { "and was thinking about using a for loop somehow."

    console.log(questions);

};
```

you can see that I try to use the includes method, which is the only thing I could get to return a bol, but for some reason it didn't actually compare the "new_answer" with the old answer. it would just return true every time. but never false regardless of them being the same.

at the bottom are other attempts/ideas but I'm too amateur at this programming thing.

here is the HTML of a single question if it's of any value.

```
div class="row" id="question_1" value="0">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="A">
      how are you?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="answer5" onclick="get_id(this, id)" value="10">
    <button id="answer5" value="10">
      5
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="answer4" onclick="get_id(this, id)" value="8">
    <button id="answer4" value="8">
      4
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="answer3" onclick="get_id(this, id)" value="5">
    <button id="answer3" value="5">
      3
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="answer2" onclick="get_id(this, id)" value="2">
    <button id="answer2" value="2">
      2
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="answer1" onclick="get_id(this, id)" value="0">
    <button id="answer1" value="0">
      1
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And yea im not even using the button properties other than style lmao.

Comment: So, you push the `new_answer` into the `questions` immediately before checking if the questions contains the new_answer. Why would that ever be false?

Comment: I recommend if you can, simply use a different data structure which would help you in manipulating the overall question response easier. An object where each question is the key and the value is the answer would make it easier to determine if the question already existed and updating that same key

Comment: JavaScript arrays can be sparse, you know. Why not simply do `questions[question_num] = new_answer`? No searching or pushing needed.

Comment: @Taplar i was aware of that, i was just doing it to for clarity and didn't want to explain that whole shibang in my question. :)

Comment: @terrymorse i will try hehe

Comment: See my answer below. BTW, you have multiple elements with the same `id`. That is invalid, all ids must be unique.

Comment: i wasnt even using the id from the buttons so i just was lazy and didn't delete them. but the functionality worked fine for the time being lol. @terrymorse

Comment: You are also setting a `value` attribute on a div. This is invalid, div has no such attribute. I changed this to `data-value` in my answer.

Comment: i noticed, it was still collecting the attribute "value" for me so i didn't think much of it. but thanks for the fleshed-out critique of my practice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over complicating the problem.

Note that the array index and the question numbers are identical, so there is no need to search for an answer in the array. It's already in its spot in the array, or not.

Push is the wrong method to add an answer to the array, as that will add to the end of the array. You want to insert the answer into its correct array position, which is simply:

```
questions[question_num] = {Question: question_num, Answer: value);
```

```js
let questions = [];

function get_id(xd) {

  let qDiv = xd.parentNode;
  let question_num = qDiv.dataset.value;
  let value = xd.firstElementChild.value;
  let new_answer = {
    Question: question_num,
    Answer: value
  };

  questions[Number(question_num)] = new_answer;

  result.innerHTML = 'questions: ' +
    JSON.stringify(questions,null,2);
};

let result = document.getElementById('result');
```

```css
#result {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
.row {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="question_1" data-value="1">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="A">
        Q1?
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="get_id(this)" value="10">
      <button value="10">5</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="get_id(this)" value="8">
      <button value="8">
      4
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="get_id(this)" value="5">
      <button value="5">
      3
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="get_id(this)" value="2">
      <button value="2">
      2
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="get_id(this)" value="0">
      <button value="0">
      1
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="question_3" data-value="3">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="A">
        Q3?
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="get_id(this)" value="10">
      <button value="10">
      5
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="get_id(this)" value="8">
      <button value="8">
      4
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="get_id(this)" value="5">
      <button id="answer3" value="5">
      3
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="get_id(this)" value="2">
      <button value="2">
      2
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="get_id(this)" value="0">
      <button id="answer1" value="0">
      1
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<pre id="result"></pre>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: hey thanks! is there a way to move up multiple parent levels? cause each set of questions sit in their own section, so you would get the question number and question section, which you would do a similar relative thing for each section? and then display all the components into a table with each question value displayed down a column for each question section. if not ill just go and do more research as well haha.

Comment: @austinb There's just `.parentElement` property, which is the parent of the element. To get other ancestors, you'd have to walk up each parent element.

Comment: so im guessing but sceptical that it would be something like. .parentElement.parentElement? @terrymorse

Answer (score 0):

To me the following seems to be the correct way of doing it.

1. Filter the questions and exclude the question that is answered
2. If it will be already in the questions it will get excluded otherwise questions will remain the same
3. Add the answered question which holds the new data.

**Code is as follows**

```
questions = questions.filter(q => q.question_num !== new_answer.question_num);

questions.push(new_answer);
```

Comment: NERD!! but actually thanks so much! very clean, ya did it in one line! I wonder what else you can do in one line. the world may never know.

Comment: so when i go to another question, it just deletes the answer for the previous question. and fills in the answer for the new question, but the array ends with only one object after every click. it still needs to add answers from different questions.

Comment: Actually this answer is giving you the exact way of how to filter it, but for the rest of the logic it needs to be evaluated separately too. But this filtering is ok as I have explained too. You need to put the right logic such that it does not filter out all the questions and ends up with one question in the end.

Comment: When your question is answered are you reloading the page? If that is so then questions array will reset to `[]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Array.findIndex` like this. and it is way cleaner

```
let questions = [];


function get_id(xd,jf){

    let question = (xd.parentNode.id);
    let question_num = document.getElementById(question).getAttribute("value");
    let number = document.getElementById(jf).getAttribute("value");
    let new_answer = {Question:question_num, Answer:number};

    const found = questions.findIndex(v => v.Question === question_num);
    if(found === -1){
      questions.push(new_answer);
      console.log("new question answered");
      console.log(questions);
      return;
    }
  
    questions[found].Answer = number;
    console.log("new question updated");
    console.log(questions);

};
```

[codepen if you want to see it :)](https://codepen.io/Ruben1985/pen/bGVypKq?editors=0011)

Comment: so it works in your lil code pen thing exactly how i want. but for some reason, when i run it on browser it still just adds a new object to the array. so in my console when it logs questions it has x many objects as i click.

Comment: you should have something wrong i tested in my local and is working. show me your code